# Why is scipy.optimize.curve_fit evaluating the initial guess repeatedly (and probably costly)?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

When using `curve_fit` the model function is repeatedly and uselessly (and probably costly) evaluated **without** changing the parameters. Why does this happen?

Consider the following example for identifying the parameters of a quadratic function:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

i=0

def f(x, a, b):
    global i; i += 1
    print('run: {:2}, p: {:<11.10}, {:<11.10}'.format(i, a, b))
    return(x**a+b)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5, 10], p0 = [1.5, 0.5])
print('\npopt:', popt)
```

Output:

```
run:  1, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  2, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  3, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  4, p: 1.500000022, 0.5        
run:  5, p: 1.5        , 0.5000000075
run:  6, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143807
run:  7, p: 2.166073071, 0.9668143807
run:  8, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143951
run:  9, p: 2.014374939, 0.9956632744
run: 10, p: 2.014374969, 0.9956632744
run: 11, p: 2.014374939, 0.9956632892
run: 12, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686478
run: 13, p: 2.000113651, 0.9999686478
run: 14, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686627
run: 15, p: 2.000000007, 0.999999998
run: 16, p: 2.000000037, 0.999999998
run: 17, p: 2.000000007, 1.000000013
run: 18, p: 2.0        , 1.0        

popt: [2. 1.]
```

The first evaluation calculates the values for the initial guess, but this is then done again in the second and third run. Only in the fourth and fifth evaluation the optimization is started by calculating the derivatives. If the function evaluations are costly and some larger-scale tolerance is acceptable, these redundant evaluations can take up a considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIth full_output (see `leastsq` docs):

```
In [125]: curve_fit(f, [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5, 10], p0 = [1.5, 0.5],full_output=True)            
run:  1, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  2, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  3, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  4, p: 1.500000022, 0.5        
run:  5, p: 1.5        , 0.5000000075
run:  6, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143807
run:  7, p: 2.166073071, 0.9668143807
run:  8, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143951
run:  9, p: 2.014374939, 0.9956632744
run: 10, p: 2.014374969, 0.9956632744
run: 11, p: 2.014374939, 0.9956632892
run: 12, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686478
run: 13, p: 2.000113651, 0.9999686478
run: 14, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686627
run: 15, p: 2.000000007, 0.999999998
run: 16, p: 2.000000037, 0.999999998
run: 17, p: 2.000000007, 1.000000013
run: 18, p: 2.0        , 1.0        
Out[125]: 
(array([2., 1.]), array([[ 0., -0.],
        [-0.,  0.]]), {'fvec': array([0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  'nfev': 16,
  'fjac': array([[-10.2688908 ,   0.        ,   0.26999885,   0.96286064],
         [ -1.2328595 ,  -1.5748198 ,   0.2521752 ,  -0.73019944]]),
  'ipvt': array([1, 2], dtype=int32),
  'qtf': array([-7.08708997e-08,  3.07498129e-09])}, 'The relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most 0.000000', 2)
```

Where the returned information is:

```
infodict : dict
a dictionary of optional outputs with the keys:

``nfev``
    The number of function calls
``fvec``
    The function evaluated at the output
``fjac``
    A permutation of the R matrix of a QR
    factorization of the final approximate
    Jacobian matrix, stored column wise.
    Together with ipvt, the covariance of the
    estimate can be approximated.
``ipvt``
    An integer array of length N which defines
    a permutation matrix, p, such that
    fjac*p = q*r, where r is upper triangular
    with diagonal elements of nonincreasing
    magnitude. Column j of p is column ipvt(j)
    of the identity matrix.
``qtf``
    The vector (transpose(q) * fvec).
```

So it's claiming to evaluate 16 times, not your 18.  So one or more of the initial evaluations might be from `curve_fit` parameter checking (or something like that).

With other methods:

```
In [134]: i=0                                                                                    
In [135]: curve_fit(f, [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5, 10], p0 = [1.5, 0.5],method='trf')                
run:  1, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  2, p: 1.500000022, 0.5        
run:  3, p: 1.5        , 0.5000000149
run:  4, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143807
run:  5, p: 2.166073071, 0.9668143807
run:  6, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143956
run:  7, p: 2.01437494 , 0.9956632758
run:  8, p: 2.01437497 , 0.9956632758
run:  9, p: 2.01437494 , 0.9956632907
run: 10, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686478
run: 11, p: 2.000113651, 0.9999686478
run: 12, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686627
run: 13, p: 2.000000007, 0.999999998
run: 14, p: 2.000000037, 0.999999998
run: 15, p: 2.000000007, 1.000000013
run: 16, p: 2.0        , 1.0        
run: 17, p: 2.00000003 , 1.0        
run: 18, p: 2.0        , 1.000000015
Out[135]: 
(array([2., 1.]), array([[ 3.77052335e-34, -1.19338002e-33],
        [-1.19338002e-33,  9.94005329e-33]]))
```

and

```
In [136]: i=0                                                                                    
In [137]: curve_fit(f, [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5, 10], p0 = [1.5, 0.5],method='dogbox')             
run:  1, p: 1.5        , 0.5        
run:  2, p: 1.500000022, 0.5        
run:  3, p: 1.5        , 0.5000000149
run:  4, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143807
run:  5, p: 2.166073071, 0.9668143807
run:  6, p: 2.166073038, 0.9668143956
run:  7, p: 2.01437494 , 0.9956632758
run:  8, p: 2.01437497 , 0.9956632758
run:  9, p: 2.01437494 , 0.9956632907
run: 10, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686478
run: 11, p: 2.000113651, 0.9999686478
run: 12, p: 2.000113621, 0.9999686627
run: 13, p: 2.000000007, 0.999999998
run: 14, p: 2.000000037, 0.999999998
run: 15, p: 2.000000007, 1.000000013
run: 16, p: 2.0        , 1.0        
run: 17, p: 2.00000003 , 1.0        
run: 18, p: 2.0        , 1.000000015
Out[137]: 
(array([2., 1.]), array([[ 3.77052335e-34, -1.19338002e-33],
        [-1.19338002e-33,  9.94005329e-33]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! To get to the bottom of the problem I tried to directly use `leastsq`: although it claims (via `nfev`) to be evaluated only 16 times , the function is in reality still evaluated 18 times. I'm also wondering why `curve_fit` uses the legacy function `leastsq` and not the newer `least_squares`.
Since my question is not really answered, I think I'll have to edit my question?

Comment: `nfev` comes from the `retval` produced by the `_minpack` call.  I see in `leastsq` at least one call to  `_check_func` (calls the function to check shape and type) prior to that.

Comment: Interestingly `least_squares` does not check the function but immediately calculates the derivatives. However, overall it requires the same number of calls as `leastsq`  (although I tried to prescribe the same accuracy).